# MDL data table will not shrink all the way

Tags: html, css, html-table, material-design-lite

I am trying to find a good way to allow an MDL data table to shrink to fit a mobile device. I have tried setting the table width to 100%.

This works as long as I also set table-layout to fixed (I am not sure why):

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

However, when trying to use this method on a selectable table the whole table gets pushed off to the right:

[image]

Without the selectable class added to the table it look like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: "fixed: Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths." (MDN)

Comment: @sweaver2112 I see. So the reason I needed table-layout: fixed was so that it would clip the sides of the table to fit the device. I guess I need to adjust the padding and/or text size of the table to make it smaller instead of using table-layout?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I know that you could possibly look into using flexbox here, see http://inlehmansterms.net/2014/10/11/responsive-tables-with-flexbox/ and https://codepen.io/vasansr/pen/gPXJxB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this (thanks to @sweaver2112 for the comments) by changing the padding on the table to make it smaller.

```
  td, th {
    padding: 12px 5px;
  }

  td:first-of-type, th:first-of-type {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }

  td:last-of-type, th:last-of-type {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
```